# Twilio Audio Output Issues

Tags: twilio

We are using Programmable Voice to implement a call center application in the browser using Twilio Javascript Client library 1.6.0. The application may receive/make calls from the application main window. Also, the user may transfer the call into a popup window so that the main application could be refreshed or navigated away.  The call transfer happens through conference call.  When a popup opens, it receives a new call and joins the conference (using the same worker) while the main window disconnects.

Everything is working fine in Firefox and Edge.  However, in Chrome and Safari we noticed some weird issues.

Chrome:
When call is transferred to a popup, and main window call disconnects, the audio still outputs through the main window, even though microphone is working correctly through a popup.  As a result when the main window refreshes, the audio is lost (even though the microphone continues to work).

Safari:

The audio output is working correctly in a popup, even after the main window is refreshed.  However, when popup is closed (call ends) and the main window receives or makes a new call, the audio is not working at all until the browser is completely restarted.

Partial Fix (for Chrome):
I've added an event (on parent window close), to reassignMasterOutput in a popup.

```
conn.mediaStream._reassignMasterOutput(conn.mediaStream, device.audio.availableOutputDevices.get('default').deviceId);
```

This fixes the audio output in the popup window.  However, if the main application window refreshes and twilio client is re-initialized, it takes over the audio output again, and this time I have no access to parent window from the popup.

EDIT

Additionally, when two separate windows are opened and same application is launched in both windows, there are no issues. Each Window will have control over its audio output. The problem only happens with popup window (or tab), somehow they are attached to one another.

Currently we are trying a new approach where twilio is setup only in the popup and all calls originate from popup (no transfer involved).  However, we are required to keep the popup open all the time (in order to receive a calls).  Another problem is when navigating the main application (in main window) and a new call received, there is not way to set focus on popup (or tab).

Any suggestions will be great.

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect us to help you if you can't figure this out to a small reproducible example.

Comment: Its not very possible to do a small example. There is a lot of backend, UI and twilio specific configuration required to make it reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Reference information: Twilio Support Case 1506585

Please send in the logging as mentioned in the support case.